# How can I reuse the same Razor Class Library from both asp.net and asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, render, .net-standard, razor-class-library

Razor Class libraries are .net standard compatible and I expect to reuse them (the razor rendering engine) from all the project types/platforms(asp.net MVC 4, asp.net core, console applications).
Is there any direct way to render the views without being coupled to the specific .net platform/framework?

Comment: Pretty sure Razor class libraries are an ASP.NET Core feature, so they won't work with traditional ASP.NET MVC with a .NET Framework app. However, they would work with an ASP.NET Core app targeting .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What about rendering the razor templates in the .net core console application? If we can do it in a .net standard compatible way then it should not be difficult to render in the traditional ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: While .NET Standard is able to be used in .NET Core and .NET Framework, it's important to emphasize that Razor class libraries are an ASP.NET Core feature. AFAIK this means traditional MVC is unable to render views in those DLLs. Yes, the DLL can be referenced in the application, but I don't believe the ASP.NET MVC engine can use the views in the binary. However you would be able to share view models and business logic between an ASP.NET Core and traditional MVC app using .NET Standard